# Exporting waypoints layers from ArcGIS for Desktop to Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, kml, google-earth

Is it possible to export waypoints Layer (ArcGIS) directly to Google Earth?

I can export waypoints tables from MapINFO directly to Google Earth via EXPORT MAP TO GOOGLE EARTH tab.

Answer (score 1):

"Data from GPS sources are usually in wgs1984 by default. Check that first then you can skip the reproject step. Rightclick on the layer in ArcMap and choose "Properties" click tab "Source" and check if the projected coordinate system is WGS 1984."

Not directly on the fly, you need to export it to kmz then open it in Google Earth. If this dont work you need to reproject it to WGS84 first.

In ArcMap I assume you created a Points layer from your waypoints "File -> add data -> Add XY data".

Here I will guide you to the process of converting it to WGS84 first, then export to kmz.

Then you go to "Geoprocessing->ArcToolBox->Data Management Tools->Projections And Transformations-->Project".

In the Project window you add your Point layer as "Input Dataset". As "Output Dataset" you browse to a folder where you want to save your reprojected Point layer and give it an appropiate name. In the "Output Coordinate System" you browse to "Geographic Coordinate Systems->World->WGS 1984". Then click OK.

Now open up your newly reprojected Point layer. Then go to "ArcToolbox->Conversion Tools->To KML->Layer To KML". As layer you add your wgs1984 Point layer. As "Output File" you browse to a folder and give the file an appropiate name. Then click "OK".

Now you get a KMZ file, wich is same as KML, its just that its compressed.

Double click on it, and if you associated Google Earth with KMZ it should open in Google Earth. Else start Google Earth and add the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

To do this there is a [Layer To KML](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/layer-to-kml.htm) tool:

> This tool converts a feature or raster layer into a KML file
>   containing a translation of Esri geometries and symbology. This file
>   is compressed using ZIP compression, has a .kmz extension, and can be
>   read by any KML client including ArcGIS Explorer, ArcGlobe, and Google
>   Earth.